# Valgrind: Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd for larger input values only

Tags: c, memory, malloc, valgrind

I'm trying to work on a Dijikstra implementation and this is the graph generation code that I have

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 300
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int v = atoi(argv[1]);
    int SIZE = v*v;
    int* adjMatrix = malloc(sizeof(int)* SIZE);
    graphGeneration(adjMatrix, v);
    free(adjMatrix);
    return 0;
}

void graphGeneration(int* adj, int numV){
    int i, j, r;
    for(i = 0; i< numV; i++){
        for(j=0; j < numV; j++){
            if(i == j){
                adj[i * numV + j] = 0;
            }
            else{
                r = rand() % MAX;
                adj[i * numV + j] = r;
                adj[j * numV + i] = r;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I try a value of v in 1000's it seems to work fine, but when I try to enter a value of v = 10,000+ I get a segfault (Specifically at 50,000 is the number I noticed). Running valgrind gets me the error in the title at this method. 
Reposting here for convenience:

```
Invalid write of size 4
at 0x400800: graphGeneration 
by 0x4006E3: main
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
```

Anyone have any ideas for how to debug this or if there are any obvious errors here?

I also noticed this bit in valgrind

```
Warning: silly arg (-7179869184) to malloc()
```

which I'm not sure if it's related, but it seems like a strange thing as well.

Comment: First, what type of argument does `malloc()` take?  Second, what does `malloc()` return when you  get the segfault?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sorry I'm not sure if I understand but I'll try my best to provide details. what I want to allocate is the size of a 2d integer array in a 1d format. (The input from commandline is the width of the array) The errors I'm getting from the compiler is just Segmentation fault      (core dumped)

Comment: With any decent modern compiler you should be able to do `sizeof(double[v][v])` so you don't have to do the computations manually. Then, check the return of `malloc` for such large allocations. Third, try your code with small examples, such that you have any chance to debug.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at some [`malloc()` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc): Its argument is of type `size_t` for a reason. `int` is not guaranteed to hold any possible object size, `size_t` is. And it is unsigned btw -- negative sizes don't make much sense.

So just write

```
size_t SIZE = ((size_t)v) * v;
```

as your `v` is an `int` you have to force this multiplication to be done as `size_t` by casting one of the arguments.

A slightly better way would be to make `v` an `unsigned long` and use `strtoul()` instead of `atoi()`.

---

Then, **check** the result of your `malloc()` before you use it. It might still return `NULL`, even with a correct size argument. If it does, this simply means you **don't have enough RAM available** at that moment.

After all, with `v=10000` and assuming an `int` takes four bytes (which is very common), you already attempt to allocate 400 MB at once.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe it's possible that it overflowed, hence the silly error? It's definitely possible, although if that happens to be the case, I'd be a little unhappy because the HPC I'm using should have a lot more RAM than 400MB. Perhaps, though, I was just not allocated the space, but changing that line to size_t doesn't seem to have changed anything for me.

Comment: Not only `SIZE` should be a `size_t`, but also `v`, so that `v*v` results already in a `size_t`. Otherwise the multiplication will be overflow if `v>=50000`.

Comment: @mch good one, I didn't look close enough at the source! will edit this answer.

Comment: For checking malloc, I just need a conditional statement that sees whether the thing I malloc'd is null or not right?

Comment: Right. Any `malloc()` **without** checking the return value is a bug. Common idiom: `x = malloc(sizeof *x); if (!x) { fputs("out of memory!", stderr); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`.

Comment: Well I did some testing for smaller numbers and it did not return NULL so that's good. I also realized that in a different function I wrote, I accidentally left the range to a small number which resulted in an absurdly low computation time. ^^; So, thanks guys for the help! But I think I might've trolled myself here by trying to allocate more memory than I actually needed.